# How to organize ballon messages loop in WinForms correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to organize the balloon messages pop-up loop where each message should be added to the previous one(s) if the balloon tip is shown at this moment (messages should be divided from each other via "\n" character).

So I wrote the following code:

```
    private void ballonMessagesProcessor(CancellationToken token)
    {
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipClosed += new EventHandler(delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "";
        });

        while (true)
        {
            string message;
            while (balloonMessages.TryDequeue(out message))
            {
                var localMessageCopy = message;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notifyIcon.BalloonTipText))
                {
                    localMessageCopy = "\n" + localMessageCopy;
                }
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    notifyIcon.BalloonTipText += localMessageCopy;
                    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
                });
            }

            var cancelled = token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0));
            if (cancelled)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it has some multithreading problems. For example, `notifyIcon.BallonTipText` can be changed from the event handler right after `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notifyIcon.BalloonTipText)` line will be executed, so it will lead to the unnecessary "\n" character added to the beginning of the balloon tip.

I think that there are a lot of other problems but I can't find them.

How can I fix it? What is the right way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using critical sections might do the trick, just share the lock between the two sections